# SQL Get MIN() and MAX() with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, min

have a problem with this code

```
SELECT b.*, MIN(c.seri) as seri_awal, MAX(c.seri) as seri_akhir FROM berkas b
LEFT JOIN certificate c
    ON c.berkas_nomor = b.nomor
```

With that code, i think i can get all the data related to the relation i created (`c.berkas_nomor = b.nomor`) and get the MIN() and MAX() values for the table that i `INNER JOIN`, but the result I get only shows 1 data ( my expectation should be 4 data )

**My expectation result**

| nomor | nama | seri_awal | seri_akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASD123 | lorem | S0000001 | S0000015 |
| ASD321 | ipsum | S1000500 | S1000525 |
| QWE123 | dolor | S3000500 | S3000525 |
| QWE321 | ameti | S4000001 | S4000015 |

**Real result**

| nomor | nama | seri_awal | seri_akhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASD123 | lorem | S0000001 | S0000015 |

is there something wrong with the code i made? Thanks

Comment: Your query is invalid. I suggest you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in order to avoid writing such invalid queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group by the 2 columns that you want the aggregate results:

```
SELECT b.nomor, b.nama, 
       MIN(c.seri) as seri_awal, 
       MAX(c.seri) as seri_akhir 
FROM berkas b LEFT JOIN certificate c
ON c.berkas_nomor = b.nomor
GROUP BY b.nomor, b.nama
```

Answer (score 1):

Subquery portion returns berkas_nomor wise min and max value and JOIN with main table berkas.

```
SELECT b.nomor, b.nama, t.seri_awal, t.seri_akhir
FROM berkas b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT berkas_nomor
                , MIN(seri) seri_awal
                , MAX(seri) seri_akhir
           FROM certificate
           GROUP BY berkas_nomor) t
      ON b.nomor = t.berkas_nomor;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `primary key` in `berkas`, then you can use that for aggregation:

```
SELECT b.*, MIN(c.seri) as seri_awal, MAX(c.seri) as seri_akhir
FROM berkas b LEFT JOIN
     certificate c
     ON c.berkas_nomor = b.nomor
GROUP BY b.nomor;
```

MySQL supports the SQL Standard where you can aggregate by a primary key but still use any columns from the specified table.