# sql- how to get min,max,ave after inner join with groupby column?

Tags: sql, pandas-groupby, inner-join

I am trying to get min, max, avg value in a column after `group by` based on another column.

From what I saw here:[SQL Get MIN() and MAX() with INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798414/sql-get-min-and-max-with-inner-join)

my syntax is correct so I am not sure what the problem is.

But I'm getting this error:

> You can only execute one statement at a time.

The code is :

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
battles=pd.read_csv('https://github.com/TheMLGuy/Game-of-Thrones-Dataset/raw/master/battles.csv')
character_deaths=pd.read_csv('https://github.com/TheMLGuy/Game-of-Thrones-Dataset/raw/master/character-deaths.csv')
character_predictions=pd.read_csv('https://github.com/TheMLGuy/Game-of-Thrones-Dataset/raw/master/character-predictions.csv')

character_deaths.loc[:,'Book_of_Death']=character_deaths.loc[:,'Book of Death']

cnx = sqlite3.connect('pythonsqlite.db')
battles.to_sql(name='battles', con=cnx, if_exists='replace')
character_deaths.to_sql(name='character_deaths', con=cnx, if_exists='replace')
character_predictions.to_sql(name='character_predictions', con=cnx, if_exists='replace')


#Edit the query
qry="""
--<<<write your query below this line>>>

SELECT MIN(character_predictions.age) as 
min_age,MAX(character_predictions.age) as 
max_age,AVG(character_predictions.age) as ave_age
FROM character_predictions
INNER JOIN character_deaths ON 
character_predictions.name = character_deaths.Name;
GROUP BY character_deaths.Book_of_Death
"""

pd.read_sql(qry, con=cnx)
```

and what I want to get is avg, min, max of 'age' column for each book (that's why I do the `group by`..)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the end of your join condition:

> ```
> INNER JOIN character_deaths ON  
> character_predictions.name = character_deaths.Name; <-- REMOVE THIS CHARACTER  
> GROUP BY character_deaths.Book_of_Death
> ```

```
qry="""
--<<<write your query below this line>>>

SELECT MIN(character_predictions.age) as 
min_age,MAX(character_predictions.age) as 
max_age,AVG(character_predictions.age) as ave_age
FROM character_predictions
INNER JOIN character_deaths ON 
character_predictions.name = character_deaths.Name
GROUP BY character_deaths.Book_of_Death;
"""
```

Comment: ok tnx question can be closed

Comment: @AsaelBarIlan To "close" the question, you just need to click on the grey tick to the left of the solution to accept it. :)